# Maven and JVM relation

Tags: java, maven, jvm, javac

Though not a direct programming question, it is related to Maven and JVM

While I was going thru this link - http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/command-line.html

Update of links: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Documentation/Troubleshooting

https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.0/release-notes.html

it says about **`MAVEN_OPTS`**

*"Specify additional options using the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable. It is for passing parameters to the Java VM when running Maven. For example, to increase the amount of memory to 1024 Meg for the entire run of Maven, use:
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m  "*

**Questions:**
How Maven is able to set the JVM properties? 
Why does Maven need JVM? It just build the war and JVM is needed only when u deploy the WAR to appserver.right?
Does Maven starts the JVM and stop it after use? IF it stops it after use, what's the point in setting more heap size?

My understanding after research:

**(1)** How/Why Maven is able to set the JVM properties?

- Maven will be able to set the JVM properties using MAVEN_OPTS.
  It is to pass the parameter to JVM for that run of Maven

**(2)** Why does Maven need JVM? Maven is just a build tool..

- Maven has to build the WAR file, right? To build the WAR file, you need to compile the code,
  and sometimes run the test cases. To compile the code, you need JVM. To run test cases you need JVM. 
  Don't know where else we need JVM when we do a mvn clean deploy.
  [eg of javac passing JVM parameters otherwise: `javac -d build/classes -classpath ... -J-Xms256m -J-Xmx1024m java-source-files`]

**(3)** Does Maven starts the JVM and stop it after use? IF it stops it after use, what's the point in setting more heap size?

- Yes , Maven starts the JVM and stop after its use. JVM is needed during its run. like if maven build needs lot of memory [like if you do XML processing] then
  setting the heap memory using MAVEN_OPTS will be helpful.

Please clarify on my understanding especially on the second question

Comment: Stop reading about Maven 1...Read about Maven 3...but Maven itself uses a JVM to run, cause it's java program.

Comment: sure thank you, updating the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `mvn` is a shell script/batch file, and it uses `MAVEN_OPTS` to do what you'd expect.
2. Maven is Java. Maven tasks are written in Java.
3. ...? Maven does a lot, and some of those things use memory. It's just a Java program. When it ends the JVM that was running it also ends.

To further clarify point 1, this is what happens at the end of the script:

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  -classpath "${M2_HOME}"/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

Note: why read Maven 1 docs?

Comment: regarding Note: I was searching for memory related things in Maven and came across that Maven 1 doc link.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is a program written in Java. This program is used to compile files, copy files, make jar files, and a whole lot of other tasks. As any Java program it needs a JVM to run. And as any Java program it uses memory. And as any Java program using memory, it can cause ot of memory errors if you don't start the JVM with enough memory.

`mvn` is able to set JVM properties because it's a simple shell script that starts a Java program: Maven.

And yes, once mvn exits, the JVM it started to run all the tasks it needs to run exits too.

Comment: OMG, I forgot just like that the very basis that Maven itself is a tool and its a program written in Java, and to run it, offcourse it needs JVM.. but your answers would give me more insight anyway.